# How to align HStack elements in center and between center element and left side of screen?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need my HStack to hold elements like the below picture:

[image]

I need the red circle in the center, and the black square placed equidistant between the left side of the screen and the leading edge of the red circle. This has to be a very common UI placement, but I can't find anything online on how to do this.

Comment: At least you have to try and provide [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Spacer()` behind the red circle in the `HStack.`

```
HStack {
    // other code here
    Spacer()
}
```

The `Spacer` will take up the available space, 1/3 of the screen, to produce the effect you wanted.